# Trait 'Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

when I tried to run `php artisan serve`, I got this one

[image]

I'm using the latest version of `laravel` which is `5.1`, and also tried composer update but then I also get the same error

[image]

Am I missing something here? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `HandlesAuthorization` trait has been added in Laravel 5.1.20.

To update, try running composer without its scripts:

> composer update --no-scripts

Comment: Tried and still getting the same :/

Comment: @FewFlyBy - Do you see the `HandlesAuthorization.php` file under `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access`? Does it contain the `HandlesAuthorization` trait?

Comment: I only see Gate.php in that folder

Comment: Then you haven't updated properly. What's the version constraint for laravel in your `composer.json` file?

Comment: Then something must have gone wrong when you updated. I'd suggest you completely nuke your `vendor` directory and run `composer update --no-scripts` again.

Comment: Nuke? you mean delete?

Comment: Yes. Completely delete your `vendor` directory, then run composer again.

Comment: Okay now, thank you! BTW, what's the use of --no-scripts?

Comment: `--no-scripts` says to ignore the scripts part within your composer.json. If you have a look in that file you'll see, that there are a lot of artisan commands. And if somethings wrong with your scripts, it'll throw an error and can't complete the `composer update`.